# Windows-hosted new site shows no preview: "Future home of something quite cool." message is displayed

Tags: https, publish, hosting, windows

I added a theme and made a sample home page.

What could cause the site to display no previews or even display no changes when published?

Note: I did my best to search similar previously-asked questions but found just one that didn't help.

Comment: I added an answer, hope that helps. I also found a ton of answers and references to similar problems by using a popular search engine to search for "future home of something quite cool"

Answer (score 0):

Probably the root directory of your web hosting is not where your Wordpress blog is, so you're seeing the default file from your web host. You'll probably find that content in an index.php or index.html in the root of your web hosting.

You may have installed your Wordpress in a directory inside the root instead of directly in the root. This would have left that default message from your webhost there, but meant that you might be accessing the Wordpress admin via that directory.

For example, the root of your webspace might look like:

```
index.php
wordpress
```

With index.php being the original file with this 'future home' message, and wordpress where you've installed your blog. When you go to yoursite.com it will load this default message, but if you go to yoursite.com/wordpress/ it will load Wordpress.

To resolve and make Wordpress load when you goto yoursite.com, first validate that this is what is happening, and if it is you can either put a redirect .htaccess in your root directory, or move everything in the wordpress directory up one directory so that Wordpress's own index.php is directly in the root of your webspace. You may also need to delete any other index.html that you find; obviously check the content first.

Comment: I made sure the installation directory of wordpress is the root directly. Still no previews!